# Display multiple dates on React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I want to display multiple dates using react calendar (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar). The issue lies in that the calendar selects all dates in between instead of each date individually.

For example, I have two dates Jun 4, 2019, and Jun 9, 2019. The calendar should only select the 4th and the 9th but it's also selecting the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th. I want to select only Jun 4 and Jun 9. I attached an example of what I want to implement using react-dates DayPickerSingleDateController. Is it possible to implement the same thing but using react-calendar?

```
<Calendar
  value={[new Date(2019, 5, 4), new Date(2019, 5, 9)]}
/>
```

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co6Gy.png)

I expect the calendar to only show these 2 dates and not the days in 
between.

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYuyT.png)

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this problem?

Comment: Not with react-calendar. I switched to react-dates DayPickerSingleDateController and it works pretty good. http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/daypickersingledatecontroller--with-some-highlighted-dates

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
          selectRange={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`selectRange` will help you to achieve your goal. Here is the [source.](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar)

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I am not sure if I was clear enough i apologize but what I want is to display Jun 4, 2019, and Jun 9, 2019 individually not with a range.

Comment: @DuaneLausell can you please paste your working code on https://codesandbox.io/ and share its public URL here.